# What is the way to create the Quiz Experience for the appearing candidate for Django Quiz app

Tags: python, django

For a QUIZ Django project, we have, an almost ready back-end for creating questions and answers. Now , I want to know, how will we organize this quiz? Some points regarding this:

- Start the quiz which will go throw N diff questions . So does the student login or just enter some basic info like email and name, and just starts by , lets say some button "Start Quiz".
- A timer also should be shown indicating remaining time. What if different questions need different timers . Like difficult questions 2 mins, but easy ones only 1 min.

  - User should not be able to reset this timer by any means (resubmit page or 
    restart quiz).
  - There needs to be a result page to show Summary . Should this "Result" be a model? (I think yes).
  - How do we ensure , user cannot retake the exam ?

I started with this idea , but I can't get past the timer thing. How do we implement this? Ideas:

- Should we use Django sessions? How?.
- Or this should be done using Javascript?.
- Should the client tell the server, if the time is almost over or the back-end server should send a signal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer them:

> Start the quiz which will go throw N diff questions . So does the student login or just enter some basic info like email and name, and just starts by , lets say some button "Start Quiz".

This really depends on the rest of your application. If this is only a one-time quiz application and no other feature exists in the application, then you don't have to implement an authentication system. But if users can have multiple quizzes at different times and you want to keep all those quizzes under a single user account, then it is better if you implement a user account system.

> A timer also should be shown indicating remaining time. What if
>   different questions need different timers . Like difficult questions 2
>   mins, but easy ones only 1 min.

I would create a `Question` model. With this approach, you can set different timer values for each specific question. If timer value is not too much vary and only some questions will have different timer values i would set a default value for this model field so i don't have to specify a value for each questions but only difficult ones.

`timer = models.SmallIntegerField(default=60) # timer value in seconds`

> User should not be able to reset this timer by any means (resubmit
>   page or restart quiz).

The only solution for this is to start and watch the timer only on the backend side. Everything on the client side can be manipulated. But timer is a `real-time like`  concept. I can think of two possible solution for this:

- Using `Websockets`: Just create an event connected to your timer on backend side and listen that event on the client side. This way, you can show exact remaining time on the client side and you can make sure it is not manipulated. [This](http://robdodson.me/building-a-countdown-timer-with-socket-dot-io/) is the first article on how to build a countdown system web sockets. I am sure you can find more.
- Two timers: Start your timer on backend then render the question page on the client side. And start a second timer on the client side based on the value of the timer on the backend. In this case, there may be milliseconds of difference between two timers (because of the response time), I think you can tolerate it. I never tried this kind of approach. I would go with websocket solution. But you can consider this option if using websockets is not an option.

> There needs to be a result page to show Summary . Should this "Result"
>   be a model? (I think yes).

I think `Yes`. Even if your application is a one-time quiz app, you may want to keep results of quizzes to allow users to `share` their results on a later time. A `Result` model would be fine.

> How do we ensure , user cannot retake the exam ?

We don't / can't. They can take new quizzes with different credentials. Even if you keep and check `IP Address of user` for uniqueness purpose, it can be reset and change. I think there is no complete solution for this. But of course, you should check `e-mail address` of user on the initial page of Quiz.

> Should we use Django sessions? How?.

Yes you can use `Django` sessions. But `NOT` for `the timer thing`.

Django sessions can help you to track the user during entire quiz process. You can store data related to quiz or the user in the session with something like,

```
request.session['e-mail'] = '....'
```

But if you implement an authentication system, things will be easier.

---

Above solutions might not be the best ones for you case. But i hope they provide you some base idea.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I finally implemented it . Keep in mind that I am using Python 2.7 and Django 1.11 . So web sockets was not a possibility .

**My models:**

```
class Question(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField('Description', max_length=300)
    difficulty_choice = (
        ('H', 'Hard'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('E', 'Easy'),
    )

    difficulty = models.CharField(
        max_length=3,
        choices=difficulty_choice,
        default='M'
                    )

    skill = models.ForeignKey(Skill, null=True)
    qset = models.ManyToManyField(QuestionSet)

    def __str__(self):  # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return "{0}".format(self.description)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Evaluator:question_details', args=[str(self.id)])


class Answer(models.Model):
    """
    Answer's Model, which is used as the answer in Question Model
    """
    detail = models.CharField(max_length=128, verbose_name=u'Answer\'s text')
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, null=True)
    correct = models.BooleanField('Correct', default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.detail
```

This solves , how to arrange for Question that will have answers and some of them are correct .

I will update the Exam solution soon.